# JQuery if then CSS background change

Tags: jquery

Basically I need a background image to change if another one is showing. This is only for one page of many. This is what I have so far but it isn't working.

```
if ($('#container').css('background') === 'url("/images/container1.png") no-repeat') {
    $('#container').css('background','url("/images/container2.png") no-repeat');
}
```

And I can't do it in CSS for one page only.

Thanks

Comment: just out of curiousity, what does `console.log( $('#container').css('background') )` show?

Comment: hmm....does `css("background-image")` or `css("background-url")` return & set the url of the background? Also, make sure you are calling this after DOM ready.

Comment: Along with @Kevin Peno's comment, why not just use `==` instead of `===`?

Comment: what is the difference between == and === ?

Comment: === is stricter in terms of types, in that a type conversion doesnt occur and thus faster - in this case the use of === is valid because only ever string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'background-image'

`if ($('#container').css('background-image') === 'url(/images/container1.png)'`

You may need to add/remove quotes from the url as well.

Comment: Does it matter if it is background: in the CSS file though?

Comment: I dont believe so as this is parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I'd suggest using class names for this. It's easier to keep straight than to constantly be updating the CSS dynamically:

```
var $myContainer = $('#container');

if ($myContainer.hasClass('background1')) {
  $myContainer
    .removeClass('background1')
    .addClass('background2');
}
```

Comment: I can't use class names, but you're right it would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").each(function(){
var current = $(this);
if( current.css('background').indexOf('some/img/url/img.png') > -1 ) {
current.css('background', 'url(new/img/url/img.png)');
}
});
```